# Acidic and basic salts with ph indicator

Tags: acid-base

Is magnesium sulfate an acidic, neutral, or basic salt? Which color will it show with the universal ph indicator?

In my opinion it needs to be slightly acidic hence turns indicator yellow

Comment: Which [pH indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator#Application)? There are dozens of them...

Comment: Universal indicator

Answer (score 1):

From the Merck Index, I see that magnesium sulphate is neutral in water : pH 6 - 7.

Comment: It's a pity nobody else can see this. Could you please provide an URL or a complete reference, if you are using a paperback version?

Comment: Here is some info in [Pubchem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Magnesium-sulfate#section=pH)